# Countries to sell paid applications from in Android Market and Apple AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store

Paid applications in Android Market can be sold only from a handful of countries. Is it also true of Apple AppStore? From which countries can you sell apps on AppStore? Is there an authoritative list somewhere?

Note: I'm not looking for list of countries in which iTunes is supported, but list of countries from which developer can sell ups.

On the AndroidMarket it works in a way that there's about a 140 countries supported for customers, but only "Merchants in Austria, France, Germany, Netherlands, Spain, U.S. and U.K. can [..] sell applications on Android Market.", see [here for source](http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134420).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/559745).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post that maybe useful...

[List of Countries Entitled to Sell Paid Apps on AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277613/list-of-countries-entitled-to-sell-paid-apps-on-appstore)

Answer (score 1):

Apple has [a Support Article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1924) up on their website, explaining you [how to determine if the iTunes Store is available in your country](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1924).

As far as I remember when submitting an application to the store, I could select one, many, or all those countries for which the app should be for sale. For some countries to be selectable, the developer might have to sign a separate contract with Apple for that specific country.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was looking for, but nevertheless is helpful. What I was looking for is a list of countries from which developer can sell apps. I.e. Google allows you to publish apps from pretty much anywhere, but if you want to charge from them you have to be in "Merchants in Austria, France, Germany, Netherlands, Spain, U.S. and U.K. can also use Google Checkout to sell applications on Android Market.". See http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134420

Answer (score 1):

Does it mean, that if the iTunes Store is availalbe in my country, that I can not only purchase but also publish paid applications?

Buying and publishing apps can look like two separate things.