# List of Countries Entitled to Sell Paid Apps on AppStore

Tags: iphone, app-store, iphone-developer-program

Do you know of an official list of supported countries that thare allowed to sell paid applications via Apple AppStore, please? **I am interested in Slovakia (Slovak Republic)**

Yesterday, I tried to join Standard iOS Developer program, but in the middle of the registration process, I received a message saying that there are issues with supporting my country (Slovakia).

I searched for a list of supported countries, but nothing was found. I wrote to Apple, but received no response yet. If you can confirm that Slovakia is free to publish and merchandise applications on Apple AppStore, that would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: Here's the latest available App Store Territories

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/AppStoreTerritories.html

Comment: Hi Steve, answerred. Thanks :-)

Comment: where is this from? which website?

Comment: -1 until source is provided - sorry.  Will +1 if updated.

Comment: also waiting for source. will +1 if source given

Comment: As edited in the answser:  EDIT: SOURCE: This is from the iTunes list of available countries to publish your apps

Comment: Hi, the page cannot be found ! update plz. tnx

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/AppStoreTerritories.html