# Official list of countries for iPhone AppStore and In-App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, list, app-store, in-app-purchase, country

I am looking for an **OFFICIAL** list of countries where :

1 - users can download **free** applications using the AppStore?

2 - users can download **paid** applications using the AppStore?

3 - users can use the In-App Purchase to buy additional features for the application (consumable, non-consumable or subscription products)?

Unfortunately, I did not manage to find one...
I have already find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277613/list-of-countries-entitled-to-sell-paid-apps-on-appstore) but the user doesn't quote his source.

Could you provide me one or several links toward the offical Apple resources where this information is available?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The full list is available during submission of an app through [iTunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com). (**EDIT:** I'd forgotten that apps are now submitted through the App Loader/Xcode, but you get the form if you edit an existing app.) The Developer Guide there shows a screenshot of the country list, though I don't know if the image is up-to-date. I'm sure the answer you pointed to simply copied-and-pasted the list from the form in iTunes Connect, as I did for this list.

Here's the full list at this time (updated with new countries as of December 2011), from the form:

Algeria
Angola
Anguilla
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina
Armenia
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas
Bahrain
Barbados
Belarus
Belgium
Belize
Bermuda
Bolivia
Botswana
Brazil
Brunei Darussalam
Bulgaria
Canada
Cayman Islands
Chile
China
Colombia
Costa Rica
Croatia
Cyprus
Czech Republic
Denmark
Dominica
Dominican Republic
Ecuador
Egypt
El Salvador
Estonia
Finland
France
Germany
Ghana
Greece
Grenada
Guatemala
Guyana
Honduras
Hong Kong
Hungary
Iceland
India
Indonesia
Ireland
Israel
Italy
Jamaica
Japan
Jordan
Kazakstan
Kenya
Korea, Republic Of
Kuwait
Latvia
Lebanon
Lithuania
Luxembourg
Macau
Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of
Madagascar
Malaysia
Mali
Malta
Mauritius
Mexico
Moldova, Republic Of
Montserrat
Netherlands
New Zealand
Nicaragua
Niger
Nigeria
Norway
Oman
Pakistan
Panama
Paraguay
Peru
Philippines
Poland
Portugal
Qatar
Romania
Russia
Saint Kitts and Nevis
Saint Lucia
Saint Vincent and The Grenadines
Saudi Arabia
Senegal
Singapore
Slovakia
Slovenia
South Africa
Spain
Sri Lanka
Suriname
Sweden
Switzerland
Taiwan
Tanzania, United Republic Of
Thailand
Trinidad and Tobago
Tunisia
Turkey
Turks and Caicos Islands
Uganda
United Arab Emirates
United Kingdom
United States
Uruguay
Uzbekistan
Venezuela
Vietnam
Virgin Islands, British
Yemen

Answer (score 4):

here's link to official list: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3599

as on May 18, 2012:

Algeria

Angola

Anguilla

Antigua & Barbuda

Argentina

Armenia

Australia

Austria

Azerbaijan

Bahamas

Bahrain

Barbados

Belarus

Belgium

Belize

Bermuda

Bolivia

Botswana

Brazil

British Virgin Islands

Brunei

Bulgaria

Canada

Cayman Islands

Chile

China

Colombia

Costa Rica

Croatia

Cyprus

Czech Republic

Denmark

Dominica

Dominican Republic

Ecuador

Egypt

El Salvador

Estonia

Finland

France

Germany

Ghana

Greece

Grenada

Guatemala

Guyana

Honduras

Hong Kong

Hungary

Iceland

India

Indonesia

Ireland

Israel

Italy

Jamaica

Japan

Jordan

Kazakhstan

Kenya

Kuwait

Latvia

Lebanon

Lithuania

Luxembourg

Macau

Macedonia

Madagascar

Malaysia

Mali

Republic of Malta

Mauritius

Mexico

Montserrat

Moldova

Netherlands

New Zealand

Nicaragua

Niger

Nigeria

Norway

Oman

Pakistan

Panama

Paraguay

Peru

Philippines

Poland

Portugal

Qatar

Romania

Russia

St. Kitts & Nevis

St. Lucia

St. Vincent & The Grenadines

Saudi Arabia

Senegal

Singapore

Slovakia

Slovenia

South Africa

South Korea

Spain

Sri Lanka

Suriname

Sweden

Switzerland

Taiwan

Tanzania

Thailand

Trinidad & Tobago

Tunisia

Turkey

Turks & Caicos

Uganda

United Arab Emirates

United Kingdom

United States

Uruguay

Uzbekistan

Venezuela

Vietnam

Yemen

Comment: The current list (2014-11-8) now has about 155 countries. Way more than 2012. Google's Play store has about 151 countries: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140

Answer (score 1):

My country is on both lists, yet only a small percentage of apps are available for download. The most popular apps are not available which is frustrating. I was told it would be too expensive for Apple to pursue getting most apps available on the US store certified in my country. I am aware that it is like this in many other countries as well.