# How can I publish paid app on iPhone app store from Pakistan?

Tags: iphone

I want to publish an iPhone app on iPhone store. App will be a paid-app. I have searched through internet but I did not find anything. I am from Pakistan.

How can I publish a paid app on iPhone app store from Pakistan?

Comment: you can do that through Xcode i believe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about publishing on the App Store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of all the countries which are entitled to see paid apps. The answer is from 2010 so more stores have probably been added.

[List of Countries Entitled to Sell Paid Apps on AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4277613/list-of-countries-entitled-to-sell-paid-apps-on-appstore)

Comment: How can i get back my revenue from iphone app store?